# Can we send email through development mode in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email

I use actionmailer in my application for email service, but i am confuse that we can send email through development mode in ruby-on-rails or we can send email only through production mode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can send email through development and ANY environment that you have configured SO LONG as you have configured the environment's config to do so. I tend to use gmail for simplicity in development mode.

An exampled as follows, I'd add to my `config/environments/development.rb`:

```
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = {:host => 'localhost:8080'}
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    :address              => "smtp.gmail.com",
    :port                 => 587,
    :domain               => 'example.com',
    :user_name            => ENV['GMAIL_ADDRESS'],
    :password             => ENV['GMAIL_PASSWORD'],
    :authentication       => 'plain',
    :enable_starttls_auto => true
  }
```

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html